# Email outlook calender invite

Tags: 2010, workflow, calendar

I have spent all day reading up on this and starting to get really frustrated..so I have turned to stack for help.

I have been tasked with making it possible so employees can more easily update their outlook calendars with new training classes and what not.  So what I wanted to do was set up a workflow that sends out an email to all employees saying something like "Blah blah blah training is now available! click here if you plan on attending"

When the employee clicks on the button I want them to be prompted with adding an event to the outlook calendar just as if they clicked the export event button.

After reading online I came up with two different links that I thought would work

1)

```
http://sharepoint/sites/<name of company>/HelpDesk/Lists/test/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={B0B0CF52-C4A6-463A-A9B0-0F9EE8513348}&CacheControl=1&ID=[%test:ID%]&Using=event.ics
```

2)

```
http://sharepoint/sites/<name of company>/HelpDesk/Lists/test/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109?Cmd=Display&CacheControl=1&List={B0B0CF52-C4A6-463A-A9B0-0F9EE8513348}&ID=[%test:ID%]&Using=Lists%2fEvents/event.ics
```

However, both links give me the error "Cannot complete this action.  Please try again."

any help/insight would be appericated, but please keep in mind I want to do this all through workflow/SharePoint designer.  If I HAVE to code then so be it, but id rather not.

Links to some pages I found:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/20/export-ical-individual-events-from-sharepoint-calendar.aspx

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:K2tihlyszYMJ:ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/email-a-calendarappointment-link-using-sharepoint-workflow/+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hijFYart2gQJ:weblogs.asp.net/wkriebel/106767+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

(company white list required me to view in cache mode)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I stumbled apon a rather simple solution (though I didn't think it would actually work :D).  Even though no one commented on this it did get one up vote so I hope my solution helps them.

What I ended up doing was pulling up the site in Google chrome, I navigated to calendar that I was using as a test and exported one of the already created events (I used the export event button under custom actions tab when viewing the event details).

With the developer tools up It captured the java script and URL that was made when the export event button was clicked.  I then proceeded to copy that URL and compared it to my URLs and made the necessary tweaks until worked the way I wanted it to.

New working link:

```
    http://sharepoint/sites/<Company Name>/HelpDesk/_vti_bin/owssvr.dllCS=109&Cmd=Display&List={<GUID>}&CacheControl=1&ID=[<ITEM ID>]&Using=event.ics&IsDlg=1
```

For the GUID the link that google chrome gives you should give you the GUID of list already and it will between {}.  You can also get the GUID from sharepoint designer. (this is the ID of the list if your really new to SharePoint)

For the Item ID you can use content look up and point it to the item you are working with.

Hope this helps anyone that is trying to do this!